# Modify Quine Mccluskey algorithm

Tags: c#, algorithm, boolean-expression

Anyone that is familiar with quine mccluskey would know that to get the implicants, we should compare the group with n number of 1s to the group with n+1 number of 1s. So my question is: Can there be a condition that would determine if we can skip the comparison between n and n+1 groups? Or reduce the number of implicants that is generated by comparing implicants?

I have to ask this because i have been implementing [quine mccluskey algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine%E2%80%93McCluskey_algorithm) in c# and when the program is solving for 12 variables, the worst case, which is when the function evaluates to 1, would take an average of 1 hour to calculate.

I have tried to count the number of loops (comparison for all the groups of n to n+1) for 12 variables and the result is 8,454,274,920 wherein 2,125,764 of it actually contains an implicant that can be combined. Its execution time is 3,938,804 milliseconds or 65.64673333333333 minutes.

Comment: I start by suggesting that you port this to a GPGPU from your CPU!